# Returning Entity from Service method is a bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've heard when you want to return some object from a service method, you have to define a DTO object (or POJO object generated with JSON Schema) instead of using an Entity.

To make it clear, here is the example:

We have an entity and a jpa repository for it:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tables")
public class Table {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String brand;
}
```

This is a **bad** practice:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private TableRepository tableRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Table create() {
        Table table = new Table();
        // Some logic for creating and saving table
        return table;
    }
}
```

This is a **good** practice:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private TableRepository tableRepository;

    @Transactional
    public TableDTO create() {
        Table table = new Table();
        // Some logic for creating and saving table
        // Logic for converting Table object to TableDTO object
        return tableDTO;
    }
}
```

Why is this so?

Thank you!

Comment: Returning a DAO (Data Access Object) is definitely *not* a good practice!! --- Returning a DTO (Data Transfer Object) would be.

Comment: Oh, yes. My mistake. DTO instead of DAO. I will edit the question.

Comment: Conciseness. In many cases your entity will contain properties that are unnecessary for a given operation. As a contrived example, shipping the full `User` entity to the client in order to print the user's name is probably overkill.

Comment: I agree, but what if I need to return exactly the same structured object? So, I don't need to configure any of its properties.

Comment: "Tomorrow" you will decide that the data is not to be stored in a local database (local to the web server), but should be accessible as a micro-service, at which point the DAO class will be changed to make a web service call, instead of connecting to the database directly. The data received from the micro-service are not "entities". If you leak implementation outside the DAO API, making changes like that in the future will require a lot of changes. Prepare for the future!

Comment: Now it is clear! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you mean a DTO (Data Transfer Object), not DAO (Data Access Object). Let me clarify this:

Data Transfer Object:

A Pojo that represents a piece of information. Usually it has aggregated data in it.

Data Access Object:

An object that performs access to some kind of persistence storage for retrieving information, someone considers it a synonym of Repository, someone not.

Entity:

An object that represents data that has been retrieved from the database.

Why is returning an Entity from the Service considered a bad practice?

The reason is that the Entity is something that is very close to the database. It contains primary key, someone could guess your database structure from it and the set of the data in case of query can be verbose. Hence, it is preferable to have some kind of logic, usually a mapper, that hides primary key and aggregates data to be less verbose and to not expose the db structure. Also, while the Entity is built on the table structure, the DTO can be customized in base of caller needs. Usually it contains exactly the data that is needed for some action and nothing more than this. Suppose you have third party software that calls your backend services: you should not expose the db structure (Entities) to this service. It is better to define a contract, with the minimal information needed for this third party service to operate, and expose only this part of the information, hiding all the rest.

Hope that's a little bit more clear now.

Edit:
Of course there are other good reasons for using DTOs instead of Entities, this is only an introductory explanation to the subject.

Comment: Well, now it's clear. Thank you! But could you please share with me other reasons for using DTOs instead of Entities?

Comment: Of course, essentially, it should be coupled with CQRS Pattern: https://henriquesd.medium.com/the-command-and-query-responsibility-segregation-cqrs-pattern-16cb7704c809

Comment: Also for decoupling the external representation from your database/business logic: https://codeopinion.com/why-use-dtos-data-transfer-objects/

Comment: In addition, when you are performing read-only operations, operations where you are not going to modify entities, using DTO's is more performant. When using entities you have the session management overhead. DTO's, on the other hand, are simple POJO's and do not participate in the session.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer! It's clear!

Comment: Another reason is that JPA entities have some invisible "magic" tied to them - behind the scenes they can be attached to a JPA session, and when you for example try to read the value of a lazy collection outside the right context you'll get a lazy loading exception. Therefore it's best to not use them beyond the transaction border, which you usually define on the service layer.